# Raspberry Pi B v1.2 Non Deterministic Dots or Splashscreen on Boot

Tags: boot, pi-b+

I'm running a basic program on a Pi B v1.2 for an embedded use case. Because of this, I would like the boot process to look as nice as possible. The best way I've seen this accomplished is with a custom splash screen so that for at least part of the time, a nice logo can be displayed. I disabled the other boot up images (such as the colored screen and moved the console output to tty3), and put my image in place of `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/pix/splash.png`. This worked great and my image was shown on boot... kind of.

I found on future boots that it would only show the image about half of the time. The other half it will display a grey screen with three white dots. This replaces the image and is animated (the dots progress like a loading bar). I've tried googling and looking through any related files I see, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where the dots are coming from, or what determines if they or the image is displayed.

I'm hoping someone will have some insight into what I've missed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a rare question in which a photo or a link to a video would've been appropriate.